# How can I include author (their archive page) in search results?

Tags: search, author

How can I include author archive pages in the default search results?

For example if I have an author name Billy Joe and I type his name into the search box a link to his author archive would display.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Relevanssi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/) can be configured to search in author names.

[image]

It doesn't search in author descriptions.

Comment: I'm wondering how this can be achieved without the use of a third party plugin.

Comment: It only lists posts that have been written by an author which matches the seach term. It does not list the author archive page as a search result :/